# BER as a function of antenna's diameter

Tags: bit-error

I hope that this community is the most suitable for this kind of question.

So I have to make a graph representing dependence of BER as a function of antenna's diameter (BER(D)) I know that antenna's gain is defined as a G = 10*log((pi^2*D^2*eta)/lambda^2). Is there any way to see how does bit error rate depend on diameter using this forumla?

Comment: Correction: G=10*log(4* pi* Area *eta/(lambda^2)). This is not the definition of G. but it tells how G is connected to antenna's area. The question is bad, because BER depends on how much there's noise (in %), what kind of noise, what's the modulation and what is the detection method. You must include much more knowledge than  the corrected G(D). There must be Xmit power, transmitter's antenna gain, distance, path losses, receiver's antenna gain, wavelength, bandwidth, receiver's noise factor and parameters of the modulation and the detection, too - system wide understanding is a must.

Comment: I recall NRZ and bi_phase have the same BER curve, and at 10dB SNR, the BER was 0.1% (0.001 error fraction). There is a 3dB change in BER, determined by how you set the noise bandwidth: as bitrate or 1/2*bitrate.

Comment: Satellite: EUTELSAT 7A, HPA: OBO = -3dB, Ku bandwidth, BER = 10e-6, modulation O-QPSK and the receiver antenna's parameters: localization: Toulouse, France, eta = 0.7, (G/T) = 20dB/K

Answer (score 1):

In simplified terms, an increase of antenna gain results in an increase in signal-to-noise ratio (SNR). The bit-error-rate (BER) decreases as SNR increases.  The amount is a function of the type of communication system being considered, especially the type of modulation. More information is needed before a quantitative answer can be given.

Comment: Modulation: O-QPSK and (G/T) = 20dB/K. I know that an increase of antenna results in decrease of BER but I have to get a chart with couple of antenna's diameters.